# Have my tyres been tampered with?

Tags: tires, service, testing

I took my car to the garage and arranged with them to replace all 4 tyres. I'd order the tyres to the garage and they'd fit them. I also asked the mechanics to check the tyres manufacturing date and to let me know if they are older than 2 years. I'd arrange for a replacement if they are old because I want a fresh set of rubber.

After I got the car back home I noticed the date code on 2 of the tyres is missing. The front and rear right are ok, both manufactured in this year (2016):
Front right: [image: front right]

Rear right: [image: rear_right]

However,  the place where the code should be on the front left tyre is blank:
[image: front left]

The code on the good tyres is surrounded in an ellipse and there are 2 blank ellipses on the front left tyre. There should be a third one as well but it's not visible. It also seems like the area has been scratched a little bit.

The rear left tyre has nothing altogether where the code should be:
[image: rear left]

Again, there are some slight signs of friction. You can argue the scratches occurred while fitting the, but I don't see how that could erase the date codes. It seems very unlikely that someone purposely scratched off the codes and I imagine it'd be very noticeable if someone did. But then again, the guys are professionals so maybe they can recover the scraped off rubber.

Is there any way to tell for certain if the tyres have been tampered with?

Comment: Check the other side of the tire.  The TIN is only required to be  fully stamped on one side.  If both sides are scuffed then I would be concerned.

Comment: @spicetraders  This is the exact answer and you should make it so.

Comment: @SteveRacer Looks like you did a great expanded write up.  Hope it solves Plesos problem, that is what this is all about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the left side wheels off, bolt them on backwards, and turn the car upside down...

Seriously, @spicetraders nailed this in the comment.  the US DOT date codes [WeekWeekYearYear] are only hot-stamped on one side, even though the raised oval or delineated area is part of the tire mold on both sides.

Because you new Goodyear Vector AS are *directional*, only the outward face on the right side of your car will "show their age".  Some manufacturers are inconsistent about which side they hot stamp (they are only obligated to do one) so you may not even get this left/right phenomenon, and which side the date code appears might appear totally random -- especially on a non-directional tire.

Soon RFID/NFC chips will be molded into the rubber, and you will be able to  scan your tire with a mobile phone app-- like checking a lost dog.